# How to truncate/round NSNumber to one decimal place

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Does anyone know how I can truncate or round an NSNumber to one decimal place?

For example, I have an NSNumber that is `1.45654` and I would like to get `1.4` or `1.5` is this possible?

I have tried using `trunc:` and `mgl_round:` (from mapbox) but they always return an integer.

this is a small snippet.

```
 let depthTruncated = NSExpression(forFunction: "trunc:", arguments: [depthValue])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few more options:

1. Do you need it to be rounded exactly to one decimal place? If so, you can use `Decimal`.

   ```
    var number = NSNumber(1.45654)

    var decimalValue = number.decimalValue
    var result: Decimal = 0
    NSDecimalRound(&result, &decimalValue, 1, .plain)
    print(result)
   ```
2. However if you just want to display it to one decimal place, you might use `NumberFormatter`.

   ```
    let number = NSNumber(1.45654)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
    guard let result = formatter.string(for: number) else { return }
    print(result)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `round` method for rounding off the decimal places.

```
let number: NSNumber = 1.45654
let roundedNumber = round(Double(truncating: number) * 10)/10
print(roundedNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks you, do you know how I can convert NSExpression to a NSNumber?

Comment: Here: `let number = NSExpression(format: equation).expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber`.

Comment: thanks again. Although it seems the snippet above is converting a string (`equation`) instead of an NSExpression. Do I need to format my NSExpression for it work above?

Comment: Ahhh I think I see my issue. I need to evaluate the expression since that returns an NSNumber.

Comment: `Double(truncating: number).rounded()` and if you would like to ceil `Double(truncating: number).rounded(.up)` or floor `Double(truncating: number).rounded(.down)`